# Error with Next Js with Expo when compiling

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, next.js

Im getting this error if I try to use the expo components in my next Js

To be clear im using an expo with next js for the web, and so I wanted both to share the same components which to my knowledge was possible but I'm getting this error.

The error is:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

and this is the next.config.js :

```
// Learn more: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/guides/using-nextjs.md#withexpo

const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter');

module.exports = withExpo({
  projectRoot: __dirname,
});
```

and this is the babel config:

```
// Learn more: https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/guides/using-nextjs.md#shared-steps

module.exports = { presets: ['@expo/next-adapter/babel'] };
```

please help and hope the info is enough

Comment: i also got this

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing next.config.js with this ( & `npm install next-images next-fonts`)

```
const { withExpo } = require('@expo/next-adapter')
const withImages = require('next-images')
const withFonts = require('next-fonts')

module.exports = withExpo(
  withImages(
    withFonts({
      projectRoot: __dirname,
    })
  )
);
```